# (Lotus Notes)Can the view set conditions (example: formula) to be shared?

Tags: view, lotus-notes, notesview

There are many outline items (menus) and many views and forms in the current running system.
The view is actually the same content, but the conditions are different.
Is there a way to have only one view and set conditions in the outer frame to display the content of the view?
for example:
There are 3 outer frame items (menu), click any outer frame item, a view will be displayed.
Menu 1 will open the view sorted by name
Menu 2 will open the view sorted by serial number
Menu 3 will open the view sorted by date

The views are all the same content, but different sorting methods are set to display.
As in the example, because there are 3 sorting methods, there are 3 views.

Is there a way to become only one view?

Comment: no, there is no way to achieve this with only one view.

Comment: A view is not like an SQL query. A view actually contains data from the documents in the view, that's what makes it so fast, no documents are accessed during the presentation of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control sorting. If you look at the [NotesUIView class](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_NOTESUIVIEW_CLASS.html), you'll see there are no methods available for that. There's not much available there at all.

The only way you can control a view from code outside the view is by embedding it in a form, subform, or page, and using the [Show Single Category](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_SHOW_SINGLE_CATEGORY_IN_EMBEDDED_VIEWS_OVER.html) feature.